# how to define a named route and download a file from database in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have my url defined in blade as:

```
href="/finance/invoices/download/{{ $invoice->file_path }}"
```

and the route in web.php is:

```
Route::get('invoices/download/{year}/{month}/{file}', 'InvoiceController@download');
```

my file is stored in the database as:

```
2018/07/invoiceberry_invoice_template_1.docx
```

edit function in my controller is:

```
public function edit(Invoice $invoice)
{
    $projectStageBillings = $invoice->projectStageBillings;

    $projectStageBilling = $projectStageBillings->first();
    $client = $projectStageBilling->projectStage->project->client;
    $client->load('projects', 'projects.stages', 'projects.stages.billings');

    $billings = [];
    foreach ($projectStageBillings as $key => $billing) {
        $billing->load('projectStage', 'projectStage.project');
        $billings[] = $billing;
    }

    return view('finance.invoice.edit')->with([
        'invoice' => $invoice,
        'clients' => Client::select('id', 'name')->get(),
        'invoice_client' => $client,
        'invoice_billings' => $billings,

    ]);
}
```

and download method is :

```
public function download($year, $month, $file, $inline = true)
{
    $headers = [
        'content-type' => 'application/pdf',
    ];

    $file_path = FileHelper::getFilePath($year, $month, $file);

    if (!$file_path) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($inline) {
        return Response::make(Storage::get($file_path), 200, $headers);
    }

    return Storage::download($file_path);
}
```

how do I get url of my file and download it?

Comment: can anyone please tell me how to do that

Comment: With just that information it is difficult to help you. What is going wrong? What is the actual URL that you see in when you open your page? And what happens if you open it?